# Graphql : JSON query parameter

Tags: json, graphql, graphql-js, apollo, apollo-server

I want to send lot of parameters to my query, and i don't want to define it.
So i try to pass JSON parameter but i  haven't lot of success with it.

I use the https://github.com/taion/graphql-type-json module.

This is my query definition :

```
usersByParams(params: JSON): [User]
```

My resolver is :

```
usersByParams: (_, { params }) => { console.log('PARAMS', params); return users; }
```

And my query is :

```
query getUsersByParams {
    usersByParams(params: {test: 'this not work'}) {
        id 
        firstName
        lastName 
        email
        password
    }
}
```

I my resolvers i always fot "FALSE" value for params.
I you have any tips for passing json
Thank's

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your resolver

```js
import GraphQLJSON from 'graphql-type-json';

JSON: {

  __serialize(value) {
    return GraphQLJSON.parseValue(value);
  }
  __parseLiteral(ast) {
    return GraphQLJSON.parseValue(value);
  }
}
```

I think this may solve your problem